# Error in producing frequency tables using multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to produce a frequency table using multiple columns. I have a large dataset, so I need to first select a few columns, convert the data to long format, then present a frequency table of only those who responded yes to the specific questions. Please see data structure below. Please note: 1 = yes and 2 = no.

data:

| subject_id | leq_1_en | leq_2_en | leq_3_en | leq_4_en |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 191-5467 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 191-6784 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 191-3457 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 191-0987 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 191-1245 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 191-2365 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 191-4589 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 191-9874 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 191-2346 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 191-1256 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 191-6784 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 191-6784 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 191-6784 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 191-6784 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Desired output:

| Variable | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| leq_1_en | 10 |
| leq_2_en | 11 |
| leq_3_en | 9 |
| leq_4_en | 11 |

What I have tried so far:

```
data %>% select(leq_1_en, leq_2_en, leq_3_en,leq_4_en) %>%
  pivot_longer (.,
    names_pattern = "([A-z]+)",
    names_to = c("groups"))  %>% 
    drop_na(value) %>% 
    group_by(groups) %>%
  count(value)
```

output:

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "call_text", value = c("... %>% count(value)", : 
replacement has 5 rows, data has 3
```

I tried to adapt the code in the linked questions below, however, it doesn't work. I am also open to using `apply` function if that is easier.

[Frequency table when there are multiple columns representing one value (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70385958/frequency-table-when-there-are-multiple-columns-representing-one-value-r)

[Adding a column of total n for each group in a stacked frequency table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70385361/adding-a-column-of-total-n-for-each-group-in-a-stacked-frequency-table)

Comment: What happens when you use summarize(n = n()) instead of count(value) in your code?

Comment: I get the same error as above and no longer gives the two tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few options to achieve this:

#### Base option

---

```
stack(colSums(data[,-1]==1))

  values      ind
1     10 leq_1_en
2     11 leq_2_en
3     10 leq_3_en
4     11 leq_4_en
```

#### Tidyverse option

---

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% select(!subject_id) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c("groups")) %>%
  drop_na(value) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = n())

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  groups       n
  <chr>    <int>
1 leq_1_en    10
2 leq_2_en    11
3 leq_3_en    10
4 leq_4_en    11
```

Your code with the `count` is working as well instead of the `summarise()`, make sure to call the `count()` from the `dplyr` package:

```
  data %>% select(!subject_id) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c("groups")) %>%
  drop_na(value) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  dplyr::count(value)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   groups [4]
  groups   value     n
  <chr>    <dbl> <int>
1 leq_1_en     1    10
2 leq_2_en     1    11
3 leq_3_en     1    10
4 leq_4_en     1    11
```

#### Data

---

```
data = structure(list(subject_id = c("191-5467 ", "191-6784 ", "191-3457 ", 
                                    "191-0987 ", "191-1245 ", "191-2365 ", "191-4589 ", "191-9874 ", 
                                    "191-2346 ", "191-1256 ", "191-6784 ", "191-6784 ", "191-6784 ", 
                                    "191-6784 "), leq_1_en = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
                                                               1, 1), leq_2_en = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                     leq_3_en = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), leq_4_en = c(1L, 
                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    -14L))
```

Comment: You could add `stack(colSums(dat[-1] == 1))` as base solution which comes a little closer to OP's desired output.

Comment: perfect!! thank you so much @bushidov. I went with the tidyverse summarise option.

Comment: I included @jay.sf answer in the "Base" option, as it is indeed closer to the desired output.